# Scope of an Vector in Java

Tags: java, vector, scope

I have a vector `r1` in the main and I want to access it in the `foo` methode.

The Line `System.out.println("in : " + r1)` gives me an error :

> r1 cannot be resolved to a variable

```
package toStack;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Stack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector r1 = new Vector<String>();
        r1.add("O1");
        r1.add("O3");

        System.out.println(foo("O3"));
    }

    public static int foo(String o){
        int num = 0;
        System.out.println("in : " + r1);
        if(r1.contains("O3"))
            num++;
        else
            System.out.println(r1);
        return num;
    }
}
```

When I compile the whole code, it gives me this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
   r1 cannot be resolved to a variable
   r1 cannot be resolved
   r1 cannot be resolved to a variable

   at toStack.Stack.foo(Stack.java:18)
   at toStack.Stack.main(Stack.java:13)
```

I tried to make the Vector static (which it looks like a stupid idea), and the same for public modifier.

Comment: The variable `r1` is declared inside the `main` method, so it's only visible inside it. You need to either pass it as a parameter or take it out as a class static field.

Comment: @Ray O'Kalahjan, we cannot declare a vector as `static` it's shows the error `illegal modifier for parameter r1`

Comment: @Salma Why did you skip the basic tutorials where all this is explained?

Comment: Because you cannot make local variables (variables defined inside a method) `static`. Only member variables can be made `static`. Learn these things in Oracle's Java Tutorials: [Learning the Java Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)

Comment: @Salma You have to **either** pass it as a parameter **or**  make it a static **field in the class**. This is, take it out of the `main` method **and** make it static **or** pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do by moving your vector initialization to class level or pass your vector to foo() as a parameter.

This would do what you wanna do;

```
public class Stack {
    static Vector r1 = new Vector<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        r1.add("O1");
        r1.add("O3");

        System.out.println(foo("O3"));
    }

    public static int foo(String o){
        int num = 0;
        System.out.println("in : " + r1);
        if(r1.contains("O3"))
            num++;
        else
            System.out.println(r1);
        return num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed !

Comment: @Salma this is what I was trying to explain, sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

This is by design, `r1` is not available in `foo` unless you pass it to `foo` as a *parameter* (or perhaps make it a `static` field in the class).

Some older languages allow you to access variables from functions higher up the call stack; Java does not.

Comment: Is there any other way to access it without passing it as a parameter ?

Comment: @Salma Make it an static field of the class, as mentioned in both his answer and my comment in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Should it be like as below??

```
package toStack;

import java.util.Vector;

public class Stack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector r1 = new Vector<String>();
        r1.add("O1");
        r1.add("O3");

        System.out.println(foo(r1));// instead of passing a String arg pass your vector arg??
    }

    //public static int foo(String o) this string argument is never used in your method so replace with your vector argument
    public static int foo(Vector r1){
        int num = 0;
        System.out.println("in : " + r1);
        if(r1.contains("O3"))
            num++;
        else
            System.out.println(r1);
        return num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `r1` how you define it currently is only visible inside your `main` method and you cannot access it inside of `foo`.

Your code sample looks as if you might just be starting to learn Java, so I suggest reading a tutorial. The official one by Oracle  (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) might be a good starting point, and in the chapter [Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) you might learn some concepts which will help you understand the compile errors you are running into.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question "Scope of an Vector in Java"

Vector belongs to **Java Collections Framework**
Vector  is similar to **ArrayList** which implements List interface but with few differences:

- Vector is synchronized which can be used in Multithreading while ArrayList is not synchronized.
- Vector increments 100% means doubles the array size if total number of element exceeds than its capacity
  while ArrayList increments 50% of array size.

By the way your code has to be corrected as mentioned by @erolkaya84

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: the questions specifies vector's scope in java. thats why I mentioned its scope. by comparing Vector with ArrayList it will be much helpful for the newbies

Comment: the scope refers as to where a variable can be accessed from, and the question is about that too, so I don't get to see what a comparison between Vector and ArrayList has to do with it?